# How to flatten an array and convert it into a string?

Tags: scala

I have an array in Scala e.g. `Array("11","112","as2")` and I want to parse it into a string:

`"['11','112','as2']"`

How can I do it in Scala?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mkString is one way to go. The scala REPL is great for this sort of thing:

```
scala> Array("11","112","as2")
res0: Array[String] = Array(11, 112, as2)

scala> "['"+res0.mkString("','")+"']"
res1: String = ['11','112','as2']
```

But if you are creating JSON, perhaps something from your JSON library would be more appropriate?

Comment: Great. No, I am creating the configuration file. By the way, does this approach also wor for `Matrix` to get something like `[[0,1] [2,1] [2,2]]`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with a Matrix class, but multi-dimensional arrays would need a two-tier approach including a map "loop" to process each of the inner arrays. For example if you have `val a = Array(Array(0,1), Array(2,1), Array(2,2))`, then `"[" + a.map("[" + _.mkString(",") + "]").mkString(",") + "]"` would give you close to your comment's wish.